# C Pipe Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pipe

I have the following code

```
    int loopval;
char *message = "D";
```

//

```
//KICK OUT THE BAD CALLS
    if(argc != 5)
        terminate("INVALID ARGUEMENTS");
//set arguements
    int num_producers;
        num_producers = atoi(argv[1]);
    int num_consumers;
        num_consumers = atoi(argv[2]);
    int items_per_producer; 
        items_per_producer = atoi(argv[3]);
    int max_in_pipe;
        max_in_pipe = atoi(argv[4]);

    ///set up the pipe
        int fd[2];
        pipe(fd);
    ////



//create producers and consumers arrays
    int producers_return_vals[num_producers];
    pthread_t producers[num_producers];

    int consumers_return_vals[num_consumers];
    pthread_t consumers[num_consumers];

//create producers threads
    for(loopval = 0; loopval < num_producers; loopval++)
    {
        producers_return_vals[loopval] = pthread_create( &producers[loopval], NULL, produce, (void*)message);
    }
//create consumers threads
    for(loopval = 0; loopval < num_consumers; loopval++)
    {
        consumers_return_vals[loopval] = pthread_create( &consumers[loopval], NULL, consume, (void*)message);
    }
//join producers
    for(loopval = 0; loopval < num_consumers; loopval++)
    {
        pthread_join(producers[loopval], NULL);
    }
//join consumers
    for(loopval = 0; loopval < num_producers; loopval++)
    {
        pthread_join(consumers[loopval], NULL);
    }

    exit(0);
```

Consumer and Producer threads are the same rright now

```
    void *consume(void *ptr)
{
    puts("HELLO FROM Consumer");
}
```

When I call `pipe(fd)` I get a segmentation fault  **EDIT** when the threads join**/EDIT**.
Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code. The error is likely elsewhere in your application. Have you tried attaching a debugger to see why the seg fault occurs?

Comment: I just added these two lines to the top of my main function, and when I comment out pipe(fd) the program runs fine

Comment: I am checking with a debugger now though

Comment: Try putting an exit(0) statement right after the pipe to see if it's indeed that (P.S. what platform are you on? just curious)

Comment: I am running on linux, and the exit(0) shows that it is not the pipe that is faulting.  I will post the rest of my code

Comment: Can you give us some context around this code?  Are you sure it's at that call and not, say, using `fd[0]` or `fd[1]` as a `FILE*` instead of a file descriptor?  Have you looked at the backtrace in gdb?

Comment: And you should check the return code.  Especially when you think there's a problem.

Comment: I do not use the pipe at all yet.  I just am creating it now.  I posted most of the code

Comment: Also, I found that the segfault happens after the pthread_join call.  But it only happens if I call pipe.  Otherwise it returns fine

Comment: I found that if I move the pipe creation down 4 lines it works fine.  Very strange

Comment: really sorry everyone for wasting your time.  It was just a stupid error.  When Joining I switched the loop control variables.  That is why the segfault happens

Comment: which parameters are you passing to the program?

Answer (score 1):

First thing to check would be the return values from `pthread_create` calls, you're storing them, but never checking the threads were actually started.

If `pthread_create` fails, then the pthread_t will be garbage which will crash `pthread_join`

EDIT:

Actually the first thing to do is compile with `-Werror -Wall` because I don't think you can declare arrays like that.

This is supposed to be C code, so move all the declarations of variables before all the code. That should highlight the problem that is probably breaking things - you can't allocate variable sized arrays on the stack like that. If you need variable sized arrays, you need to `malloc` the space on the heap.

Comment: Those are C99 variably modified declarations.  They're fine.

Comment: Definitely check all error return codes. Make yourself a macro or function to check the code, print the error and abort, then wrap the calls with it.

Comment: @Zack I stand corrected - I guess I've never been able to use C99, so haven't really looked at it.

Comment: gcc allows you to allocate variable length arrays on the stack (not static in the heap, obviously) unless you specify `-pedantic` with a standard <= `[c|gnu]90` or explicitly with `-Werror=vla` so it appears `c99` allows them.

Answer (score 0):

Okay the problem is not in the pipe ... BUT in the actual declaration:

```
int producers_return_vals[num_producers];
pthread_t producers[num_producers];
```

Typically dynamic allocation of arrays use _alloca call; If the alloca call is buggy (which it tends to be on a surprisingly large number of platforms) or If your compiler does not support dynamic allocations (which version of C compiler are you using?) then you could run into a SIGSEG...  Make sure you are using a compiler that supports c99 because that's where dynamic allocations become available.